# Difference between cross section and probability of interaction

Tags: nuclear-physics, probability, interactions, scattering-cross-section

When I read some textbooks I find that the definition of cross section is the
probability. Of incident neutron interact with a matter .but I find many other (cross section of fission, scattering, absorption..)
And I find another definition of probability of interaction in distance $l$ which is given by

$P(l)=1-e^{\frac{l}{\lambda}}$

Where $\lambda=\frac{1}{\Sigma} $
And $\Sigma$ is the macroscopic cross section $\Sigma=N \sigma$, $N$ is the density of nuclear and $\sigma$ is the croos section

My question is what is the difference between the two definition?and if we want to know if an incident particle is interact with nuclear who is the better and give experiment result?

For example if we send neutron into $Po^{209}$ what is all the cross section that we should take it into consideration

Comment: Before answering your question, can you please comment on the limit where $l\rightarrow\infty$ because $P(l)\rightarrow -\infty$ in that case! Shouldn't $0\leq P(l)\leq 1$? Should it be $P(l)=1-e^{-\frac{l}{\lambda}}$?

Comment: @Newbie is correct.  Please see my answer.

Comment: @JohnDarby Just upvoted it. Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

For nuclear reactions the following definitions are typically used.

The cross section $\sigma$ for a particular reaction can be defined as "the fraction of the incident particles which undergo the specific reaction, divided by the number of target nuclei per unit area of a thin target". [Evans, The Atomic Nucleus]  The cross section is the effective area per single target nucleus for the reaction. [Glasstone and Edlund, The Elements of Nuclear Reactor Theory] The cross section has units of area, typically expressed in barns where one barn = $10^{-24} cm^2$.  The cross section is sometimes called the "microscopic cross section" to distinguish it from the "macroscopic cross section" defined below.

The product of the (microscopic) cross section $\sigma$ and the density of target nuclei $N$ is called the "macroscopic cross section" $\Sigma = \sigma N$. $\Sigma$ is the probability of the reaction per unit path length and has units of inverse distance. The macroscopic cross section is typically expressed in $cm^{-1}$.

For incident particles with density $n$ and velocity $v$, the flux is defined as $\phi = nv$.  The reaction rate for a particular reaction with target nuclei is $\Sigma \phi$ reactions per $cm^3 \over sec$.

The probability that an incident particle will have a first interaction over a distance $l$ is $\int_{0}^{l}e^{-\Sigma x} \Sigma dx = 1 - e^{-\Sigma l}$. $\Sigma$ is sometimes denoted as $1/\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the mean free path for the reaction in $cm$.

If you bombard $Po^{209}$ neutrons, $\sigma_a$ is the basic dimension needed for the reaction type $a$, but you also need to know $N_{Po^{209}}$ and $\phi$ for your particular condition to evaluate the reaction rate $\Sigma_{a} \phi$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the word cross section is used for different things in different fields and maybe even falsely by some people. I'm personally used to the definition in particle physics, where the cross section has the units of an area and has to be multiplied with multiple other quantities which describe the experiment (e.g. beam flux and target density) to gain a reaction rate which may be nearest to a probability. Therefore people may call it a probability.

The definition your formulas are coming from is different. It comes from the "Absorption cross section". If you just search for "cross section" on Wikipedia, it will give you a range of different meanings.

For your example I would guess you are looking for the neutron cross section which has it's own article.

Comment: If we throw a neutrons to Po and use the formula above and say that 5% of particle are interact and 95% are pas is that true (or the formula use to  other thing

Comment: I have no idea from where you have your numbers, but I would say that you should NOT use above formula, as it is from a different definition of a cross section.

Comment: So can you give the true formula to know the probality of interact neutron with material

Comment: Like I said, you will find it, if you search "Neutron cross section" on Wikipedia.

Comment: $V=\sigma vdt $ do you mean this formula

Comment: That formula is merely for understanding the principle. I fear I cannot help you without knowing what is given and what you want to have as result. I would guess that calculating the cross section for Po from first principles is rather hard or even impossible because of the huge number of microscopic participants and reaction types. You will have to look it up. Maybe this tool which was also linked on Wikipedia will help you? http://xsplot.com/

Comment: $r=\sigma \,\Phi$ seems to be the formula you are searching. For a given cross section you then need a neutron flux $\Phi$ and you will get the reaction rate. I think the problem is that one uses the cross sections for macroscopic calculations where you have a lot of incoming neutrons which are homogeneous in space and some of them will react, some not. It doesn't seem to be the right tool for calculating what happens when you send a single neutron.

Comment: $r=\sigma \phi $ is the only formula that help to compute the probability of iteraction many neutron with po .what about  the formula above what is his role

Comment: Can you answer this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/540211/interaction-of-neutron-with-polonium